# Concatenating of the strings of the each paragraph

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

Is there way concatenate the strings of the each paragraph in one line? For example, I have many the same paragraphs with the space between them, it looks like:

[image: this]

Is there way to put each such paragraph in one string?

This table is my desired table:

[image: that]

I placed # there with purpose to devide it further in columns in pandas, but it turned out, I need some pre-preparations for it.

Comment: Can you clarify how you would like to approach this problem? The question tags are excel and csv (and iptables, ignoring that), but it isn't clear what you are trying to do and where you are trying to do it. Can you add to your question what you expect the final result to look like? There are an infinite number of ways to interpret "concatenate these strings."

Comment: I didnt want to tag iptables, i wrote table and it seems, that it was changed to iptables. I just deleted this tag. I have written my final desirable result, i dont know how to speak it in another way, but it seems you want to help, so i'll try: I want table with such rows, built from each paragraph, to devide them then with special symbol # by key words to build columns while i will parse it with pandas

Comment: At least provide some cell addresses. Which cells do you wish to concatenate into which cell? Or do you just want to strip out multiple linefeeds from the text in a given cell? Please provide some clarity.

Comment: You could use the `textjoin` formula. Then if your "paragraphs" weres well-formed I guess you could do something like this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-text-to-a-table-or-a-table-to-text-b5ce45db-52d5-4fe3-8e9c-e04b62f189e1